# How to use the url_for method in my own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm writing my own ruby gem and I have to use the url_for ActionView method. I just want to know how I can use that method in my gem with the defined routes in my rails app to generate the url paths by sending controller, action (and etc) params to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to pass the view object from the app into your gem methods when needed.

For example a template your app might say:

```
<%= some_gem_method(self) %>
```

And the gem could implement the method like:

```
def some_gem_method view
  view.url_for controller: "widgets", action: "show"
end
```

Comment: Note that all URL helpers are also available in the module `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, if you need to go the route of dependency lookup rather than dependency injection ;)  Dependency injection is usually better for testing purposes though.