# use url_for in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rubygems

Im writing a gem that includes some views and in one of those I need to use the `link_to` method which depends the `url_for` method. Both aren't available by default so I tried to include the needed Modules

```
include ActionView::Helpers
include ActionDispatch::Routing
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

What doesnt work because `Rails.application` is `nil` so I cant get the routes and the contained url helpers. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574866/how-to-use-the-url-for-method-in-my-own-gem) approach but I dont like it because its quick and dirty. I want the module to be included after the init so I can access the routes. Is there any way to arrange such sutuation?

Comment: did you try to include `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` directly?

Comment: Yes but it didnt help a thing: `NoMethodError: undefined method `url_for' for main:Object`

Comment: What if you call the link_to method through `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.link_to`?

Comment: That wont work when the module isn't included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. It isn't necessary to include the modules. This code does not work on the console because the rails environment isn't loaded there completely but when I start the application it works fine. Didn't think about it till now,... just kept hanging at the point it didn't work in the console.